# com.impetus.kundera.utils.InvalidConfigurationException: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath

Tags: jboss7.x, persistence.xml, kundera

I am trying to deploy sample war file build using `Kundera on jboss AS7.1.1.final`.

Here are the steps which I have followed:

### 1. created a module (com.impetus.kundera), here is module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.impetus.kundera" slot="2.0.7">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="kundera-core-2.0.7-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="cglib-2.2.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <!-- Insert resources here -->
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
    <module name="org.javassist"/>
    <module name="org.slf4j"/>
    <module name="org.apache.commons.lang"/>
    <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
</dependencies>
```

### Copied resource root path jars under 2.0.7 folder.

2. **Modified persistence.xml for:**

> <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule"
>   value="com.impetus.kundera:2.0.7" />

**Note:** My persistence.xml is under `deployment/KunderaSampleApp.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF` folder, but somehow I am getting given below error:

---

> org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."KunderaSampleApp.war#personnel_cass_pu": Failed
>   to start service
>             at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_15]
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_15]
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_15] Caused by: com.impetus.kundera.loader.PersistenceLoaderException:
>   com.impetus.kundera.utils.InvalidConfigurationException: Could not
>   find any META-INF/persistence.xml  file in the classpath
>             at com.impetus.kundera.configure.PersistenceUnitConfiguration.configure(PersistenceUnitConfiguration.java:102)
>             at com.impetus.kundera.configure.Configurator.configure(Configurator.java:63)
>             at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.initializeKundera(KunderaPersistence.java:96)
>             at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(KunderaPersistence.java:71)
>             at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(KunderaPersistence.java:58)
>             at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
>             at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
>             at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>             at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>             ... 3 more Caused by: com.impetus.kundera.utils.InvalidConfigurationException: Could not
>   find any META-INF/persistence.xml  file in the classpath
>             at com.impetus.kundera.configure.PersistenceUnitConfiguration.findPersistenceMetadatas(PersistenceUnitConfiguration.java:130)
>             at com.impetus.kundera.configure.PersistenceUnitConfiguration.configure(PersistenceUnitConfiguration.java:86)
>             ... 11 more
>       19:17:46,590 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."KunderaSampleApp.war#address_mongo_pu":
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."KunderaSampleApp.war#address_mongo_pu": Failed
>   to start service
>             at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_15]
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_15]
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_15] Caused by: com.impetus.kundera.loader.PersistenceLoaderException:
>   com.impetus.kundera.utils.InvalidConfigurationException: Could not
>   find any META-INF/persistence.xml  file in the classpath
>             at com.impetus.kundera.configure.PersistenceUnitConfiguration.configure(PersistenceUnitConfiguration.java:102)
>             at com.impetus.kundera.configure.Configurator.configure(Configurator.java:63)
>             at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.initializeKundera(KunderaPersistence.java:96)
>             at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(KunderaPersistence.java:71)
>             at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(KunderaPersistence.java:58)
>             at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
>             at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
>             at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>             at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>             ... 3 more Caused by: com.impetus.kundera.utils.InvalidConfigurationException: Could not
>   find any META-INF/persistence.xml  file in the classpath
>             at com.impetus.kundera.configure.PersistenceUnitConfiguration.findPersistenceMetadatas(PersistenceUnitConfiguration.java:130)
>             at com.impetus.kundera.configure.PersistenceUnitConfiguration.configure(PersistenceUnitConfiguration.java:86)
>             ... 11 more

---

It is working absolutely fine with `JBoss AS5CR2`.

Any pointer to issue will be a great help!

-Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can just replace the JPA implementation like that. You can have a look at https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToUseEclipseLinkWithAS7 which may give some help, but I'm not sure it of any details.

You might have better luck asking in the [JBoss Comunity forums](https://community.jboss.org/community/jbossas7/dev?view=discussions).

Also you shouldn't need to add the commons-logging library. Just use `<module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>`.